# GMSPlacePicker iOS 9 issue - ios - EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: crash, ios9

In iOS 9 GMSPlacePicker getting crashed as soon as we press back button without selecting any location on the picker view, while working fine with iOS 8.

**Error**

> *** -[UIWindow _shouldAnimatePropertyWithKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance

**Code**

```
@interface GMSViewController ()

@property(nonatomic,strong) GMSPlacePicker *placePicker;

@end

@implementation GMSViewController{}

- (instancetype)init {
if ((self = [super init])) {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D southWestSydney = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.8659, 151.1953);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D northEastSydney = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.8645, 151.1969);
    GMSCoordinateBounds *sydneyBounds =
    [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:southWestSydney coordinate:northEastSydney];
    GMSPlacePickerConfig *config =
    [[GMSPlacePickerConfig alloc] initWithViewport:sydneyBounds];
    _placePicker = [[GMSPlacePicker alloc] initWithConfig:config];
}
return self;}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
textView.delegate = self;
textView.editable = NO;
[self.view addSubview:textView];
__weak UITextView *weakResultView = textView;
[_placePicker pickPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlace *place, NSError *error) {
    UITextView *resultView = weakResultView;
    if (resultView == nil) {
        return;
    }
    if (place) {
        NSMutableAttributedString *text =
        [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[place description]];
        [text appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n\n"]];
        [text appendAttributedString:place.attributions];
        resultView.attributedText = text;
    } else if (error) {
        resultView.text =
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Place picking failed with error: %@", error];
    } else {
        resultView.text = @"Place picking cancelled.";
    }
}];}
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: These kind of errors almost always come down to zombie objects. Although it might have worked in iOS 8, but it must have been due to another specification been implemented differently. I'm not sure is it really a bug or what. The only help I can offer is to check for the zombies: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/Instruments_help_articles/FindingMessagesSenttoDeallocatedObjects/FindingMessagesSenttoDeallocatedObjects.html Please read carefully about the implications of this test,. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i have already checked for zombies, no success.

Comment: Can you provide us with the way you are presenting `GMSPlacePicker`? is it possible that the place picker is presenting through adding a new window and then gets released before the dismiss happens? is the place picker a weak refer object? I mean, if I could see some codes I could have helped some more.

Comment: I printed keywindow property, it creates a new window and it gets deallocated as we press back button, but I have already made it strong.I have also updated the code in the question.

Comment: I think you might want to try and replace the presentation code from `viewDidLoad:` to somewhere like `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` and see if it helps.

Comment: I am getting same issue no sucess

Comment: I'm having the same issue.